# Find method in std::wstring

Tags: c++, string, wstring

I have declared `Wstring` as follows

```
wstring strID
```

When I try to find the occurrences sub-string as follows

```
int index =   strID.find("LABS");
```

I am getting error like the following

```
error C2664: 'unsigned int std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::find(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &,unsigned int) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [13]' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'
```

Can you please help me to find the occurrences of sub-string?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When searching a wstring, you need to have the parameter as a wide string as well

```
int index =   strID.find(L"LABS"); 
                         ^
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int index =   strID.find(L"LABS");
```

EDIT:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Your answer is right, but would be much more informative if you would provide a short explanation of the *why*.