# strstr - string.h miscommunication error?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, winapi, string.h

I am trying to compare the file name against a list of strings to see if they match up and if they do then return accordingly

I am using the following condition:

```
if (strstr(file, str) != NULL) {
    return 1;
}
```

Though MSVC++2012 prompts me with the following error on `strstr`:

```
Error: no instance of overloaded function "strstr" matches the argument list
argument types are: (WCHAR [260], char *)
```

The question is: what is the meaning of the error above and how could it be fixed?

Comment: I would suggest replacing that with `std::wstring` and its `find` member.

Comment: You're trying to compare a Unicode string with a multibyte string, and there's no built-in function to do that. You would need to convert one to the other (most probably, convert the multibyte string to Unicode with `MultiByteToWideString`) first.

Comment: @chris > How would I do that in my case? Given that file is actually a WCHAR?

Comment: @user3267146 You alternatively could consider using UTF-16 strings *everywhere*, and then you could use `wcsstr` instead of `strstr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have got comes out from the fact that the [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) function expects to see two `char` pointers (`char *`) as its arguments, but it receives the `WCHAR` array instead as the first argument.

Unlike the usual 8-bit char, [`WCHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269344%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx) represents a 16-bit Unicode character.

The one way to fix your error is to convert your Unicode file name to the char array as following:

```
char cfile[260];
char DefChar = ' ';
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, file, -1, cfile, 260, &DefChar, NULL);
```

And then use `cfile` instead of `file`.

But this approach will only work with ASCII characters.

For that reason, you could consider using another string comparison method, suitable for the `WCHAR` strings ([`wstring`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/)).

The following code might help you with that second approach:

```
// Initialize the wstring for file
std::wstring wsfile (file);    

// Initialize the string for str
std::string sstr(str);

// Initialize the wstring for str
std::wstring wstr(sstr.begin(), sstr.end());

// Try to find the wstr in the wsfile
int index = wsfile.find(wstr); 

// Check if something was found
if(index != wstring::npos) {
    return 1;
}
```

The good SO answer about usage of the `find` method in `std::wsting`: [Find method in std::wstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644847/find-method-in-stdwstring).

More on converting `string` to `wstring`: [Mijalko: Convert std::string to std::wstring](http://blog.mijalko.com/2008/06/convert-stdstring-to-stdwstring.html).

Please leave some feedback in comments if it does not help.

Comment: Note that the creation and `assign` call of `wstr` can be merged into one constructor call.